dependent dropdown country and sity error in vue 3 pinia
I have code to create a country and city-dependent dropdown using Vue 3 pinia store, but every time I click and select data country then the data city will always be reloaded continuously and it can't stop.
FRONTEND WITH VUE 3 PINIA :
COUNTRY STORES:
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import axios from "axios";
import router from "../../../router";

export const countryStore = defineStore("country", {
  state: () => ({
    dataCountry: null,
  }),

  getters: {
    country: (state) => {
      state.dataCountry;
    },
  },

  actions: {
    async getCountry() {
      const response = await axios.get("/api/get-country");
      this.dataCountry = response.data.data;
    },
  },
});

CITY STORES:
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import axios from "axios";
import router from "../../../router";

export const cityStore = defineStore("city", {
  state: () => ({
    dataCity: null,
  }),

  getters: {
    city: (state) => {
      state.dataDistrict;
    },
  },

  actions: {
    async getCity(value) {
      const response = await axios.get("/api/get-city?country=" + value);
      this.dataCity = response.data.data;
    },
  },
});

FILE VUE:
<template>
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <label for="country" class="form-label">Country</label>
  <Select2 id="country" v-model="form.countid" :options="countries.dataCountry" :change="listCities(form.countid)" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <label for="city" class="form-label">City</label>
  <Select2 id="city" v-model="form.citid" :options="cities.dataCity" />
 </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { countryStore } from "../stores/countryStore ";
import { cityStore} from "../stores/cityStore";
import select2 from "select2";

select2();

const countries= countryStore ();
const cities = cityStore();

const listCities = async (value) => {
   cities.dataCity(value);
};

onMounted(async () => {
  countries.dataCountry();
  // cities.dataCity();
});
</script>


The the data as in the network request or as in a Vue state? Try to narrow down if it's a backend or frontend issue first using the devtools.

This problem is on the frontend (vue3)

Few things: you have some async but you also need the await in your functions, this is how it works (ESLint should complain). Also, why do you never call getCity or getCountry? Aren't those supposed to reach the endpoint to fetch the collections you want to work with? Update this and please double-check that the request is properly sent and received with the devtools, network tab. Finally, shouldn't select2() be used after all of the calls are done, rather than before them? Additionally, do you maybe see some errors in your browser console?

The request and data have been completed and the console doesn't provide a problem notification, it's just that every time I select country, the city data will continue to reload, is this the effect of onMounted?
if yes how to solve it

What do you mean exactly by reload here? The lifecycle doesn’t do this by default no.
